# how to collect the name and the value stored in a model to a list in c# mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The data comes bound in the model as parameters to my function. What I need to do is collect the name of the properties inside the model into a list, which I have done already. Also I need to store the values that comes bound in the model into a list, then add these values and convert it into json so that I can load it into grid easily. My problem is I am not being able to collect the values that comes bound in the model in a list.

This is my code.

```
 public List<string> GetPropertiesNameOfClass(UserModel olduser,UserModel newuser)
    {
        List<string> propertyNameList = new List<string>();
        List<string> propertyOldValue = new List<string>();
        List<string> propertyNewValue = new List<string>();


        if (olduser != null)
        {

            foreach (var prop in olduser.GetType().GetProperties())
            {

                propertyNameList.Add(prop.Name);

               // propertyOldValue = prop.GetValue(olduser, null);

                //var value = prop.GetValue(this) ;

            }

        }
        if(newuser !=null)
        {
            foreach(var prp in newuser.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                //propertyNewValue = prp.GetValue(this);
            }
        }

       // return propertyList + propertyOldValue + propertyNewValue;
    }
```

I get the list of property names through 
 propertyNameList.Add(prop.Name); but for values I couldn't get idea how to bind them in a list. Please help. 
I visited this link already but couldn't implement on my own.

[How to get property name and value from generic model with generic list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779502/how-to-get-property-name-and-value-from-generic-model-with-generic-list)

Comment: propertyOldValue.Add(prop.GetValue(olduser)); will give you a list of values in oldUser object. Same for newUser. Not sure exactly you want to achieve. Can you show an example of output you want.

Comment: @SBirthare propertyOldValue.Add(prop.GetValue(olduser)); is not accepted. It says System.Collections.Generic.List<string>.Add(string) has some invalid arguments

Comment: You need to convert the value. I am not running the code, check the return value from GetValue method and convert it. May be just ToString() will work:   propertyOldValue.Add(prop.GetValue(olduser).ToString());

Comment: More importantly if you explain what output you are expecting, people can help you faster.

Comment: The return type is  System.Object And the output I need is to create a json which contains the properties of the model at one level and the respective values for it at another level. So that I can load it on the grid in this way:

Comment: Column  OldValue    NewValue    
Name    khusbu      khusbu
Address asdfa       asdfasd
Age     10          12

Comment: Sorry couldn't edit this format of data to be loaded in grid. I hope It makes some sense.

Comment: Can you add that output in your question (edit) in a table format as you want to display on your UI.

Comment: @khusbugupta can you add your model to the code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think this might be what you are trying to do but it is hard to know without seeing your model and your expected output properly formatted.

```
public List<string> GetPropertiesNameOfClass(UserModel olduser, UserModel newuser)
{
    var propertyNameList = new List<string>();
    var propertyOldValue = new List<object>();
    var propertyNewValue = new List<object>();

    foreach (var prop in olduser.GetType().GetProperties())
    {

        propertyNameList.Add(prop.Name);

        propertyOldValue.Add(prop.GetValue(olduser, null));

    }

    if(newuser !=null)
    {
        foreach(var prp in newuser.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            propertyNewValue.Add(prp.GetValue(olduser, null));
        }
    }

    /* Convert To JSON Here */

    return formattedJson;
}
```

When you are adding an item to a list you can't use the + opperator you need to use Add() for a single object or AddRange() for a list of objects.

GetValue was returning an object so I changed the the lists that you were adding to the type List. For some reason ToString didn't work on the object returned by GetValue.

Some pointers for your next steps.

1. Change the return type to JSON
2. Look at using a Dictionary to structure your data. It might be useful to create an Object type to represent an old and new user together

   ```
   public class UserHistory
   {
       UserModel oldUser {get; set}
       UserModel newUser {get; set}
   }
   ```

If you can provide more information around how to structure your data I can help you out further.

Comment: thanks it worked. Now how will I add these three variables into a single variable because AddRange() takes only a single argument and I need to add three variables in which one is the list of string type and others two are the list of object types

Comment: A list isn't the correct data structure for what you want to do. I think you need to use a Dictionary that has a string as a key and takes an object list. Something like var propertyNameList = new Dictionary<string><List<object>>(); Check out http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: after studying these links I did this but couldn't add these three elements into the dictionary. Please help me am I doing right? `var result = new Dictionary<List<string>, Dictionary<List<object>, List<object>>>();   result.Add(propertyNameList, propertyOldValue, propertyNewValue);
            var formattedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
            return formattedJson; `        But It says 3 arguments are not allowed in Add()

Comment: Add() takes 2 arguments a key and a value. result.Add(key,value); Normally you would add multiple values to a list using a foreach loop. You need to break what you're trying to do into smaller steps. First you should create the dictionaries that will be the values to the result dictionary. Then add these dictionaries to the result. Try looking into key value pairs. This is getting off topic from the original question maybe open a new question describing your model, how you want your data to be structured and the expected output. Link the new question to this one and I can help you further