# how to collect the name and values stored in a model to a dictionary and finally merge these separate variables into one in c# mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

my question is continued from this link [how to collect the name and the value stored in a model to a list in c# mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27058711/how-to-collect-the-name-and-the-value-stored-in-a-model-to-a-list-in-c-sharp-mvc/27063169?noredirect=1#comment42684589_27063169) My model is like this

```
public class UserModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

I collect two different values that comes bound in this model as old value and new value which I can send as parameter to my function.I want to collect the name of these properties of this model as Int, Name,Age,Address in one variable, then its corresponding old value and new value in two different variables using Dictionary data structure so that at last I can merge these three different variable into a single and convert them into json to load them in my grid properly. I want to display my data in grid in this way.

Column   OldValue NewValue

---

Name     john     john1

---

Address   adf     adfret

---

Age        10      11

I have already done this in list.But since I could not merge three separate variables in different variable in list I want to do this using dictionary data structure.Please help.

Comment: Are you using a jquery grid that specifically requires you to pass a dictionary in order to build the grid?

Comment: @StephenMuecke no dictionary is not specifically required, I want to use it so that I can add three separate variable values into one in this specific format

Comment: @Jeff Finn my question is continued here please help

Comment: Then all you need is to pass a collection (could be anonymous object) containing 3 properties e.g. `ColumnName`, `OldValue` and `NewValue`. No need for a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of a dictionary seems unnecessary and I'm not sure how that would solve you problem. I suggest you create a class that contains the 3 properties you want to display in the view

```
public class PropertiesVM
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object OldValue { get; set; }
    public object NewValue { get; set; }
}
```

and in the controller

```
public JsonResult GetProperties()
{
  UserModel old = //
  UserModel new = //
  List<PropertiesVM> model = new List<PropertiesVM>();
  foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in typeof(UserModel).GetProperties())
  {
    PropertiesVM prop = new PropertiesVM();
    prop.Name = propertyInfo.Name;
    prop.OldValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(old, null);
    prop.NewValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(new, null);
    propertyNameList.Add(prop);
  }
  return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and in the ajax success callback, something like

```
$.each(data, function(index, item) {
  var row = $('<tr></tr>');
  row.append($('<td></td>').text(item.Name));
  row.append($('<td></td>').text(item.OldValue));
  row.append($('<td></td>').text(item.NewValue));
  $('table').append(row);
});
```

Comment: what is `typeof(Student)` overhere?

Comment: This answer helped me a lot. But I want to make it dynamic. The way we have put here typeof(UserModel), now the UserModel is not fixed here and I would obtain it at run time in this way.var modelname = mcmodel.ModelName;
            string fullName = "MessageCompose.Models." + modelname;
            Type type = Type.GetType(fullName);
            Object obj = (Activator.CreateInstance(type)); So instead of typeof(UserModel) I want something like typeof(obj) But this is not allowed here. Please help me how to do this.

Comment: `.GetProperties` is just a method of `Type`. If you have `Type type = Type.GetType(fullName);`, then just use `foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in type.GetProperties()) {...`